# Aligning a span inside a div in the center and the middle

Tags: html, css

I have a div inside which I have many spans in line. The div is fairly large and the spans don't fill it up. I want the spans to be so aligned that the resulting text appears to be in the center of the div area - both vertically and horizontally. I don't want to have to calculate the number of pixels every time I have to set it right. I am able to vertically align them in the center but not horizontally.

```
<div class="Container">
    <div class="InnerContainer">
        <b><span class="large">Hi</span><span class="normal">How're you doing</span>
        <br/>
        <span style="font-family: Arial; font-size: medium">Answer Here</span>
    </div>
</div>

.Container {
            /*Set surroundings of the div*/
            padding: 0;

            /* Set size of the div */
            width: 400px;
            height: 350px;

            /* Set position of the div */
            position: relative;
            margin: 0 auto;
            margin-left: -200px;
            margin-top: -175px;
            left: 50%;
            top: 50%;

            align-content: center;
            vertical-align: middle;
        }

        .InnerContainer{
            /*Set surroundings of the div*/
            padding: 0;

            /* Set size of the div */
            width: 400px;
            height: 350px;

            /* Set position of the div */
            position: relative;
            margin: 0 auto;
            margin-left: -250px;
            margin-top: -175px;
            left: 50%;
            top: 50%;

            /*align-content: center;*/
            vertical-align: middle;

            display: table-cell;
        }
```

Comment: Could you provide a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)? BTW, if you are setting your `.InnerContainer` to `display: table-cell`, I think you need to set the parent (`.Container`) to `display: table`.

Answer (score 0):

You should add `display:table-cell` to `.Container` and `display:inline-block` to `.InnerContainer` (because divs tend to occupy all available horizontal space unless width specified).

And than add `text-align:center; vertical-align:middle;` to `.Container`.

Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/fd5rV/

Answer (score 0):

You should use the "display: table-cell" and "vertical-align: middle;" to the parent component. And do not set the size of the child component. Do like that:

```css
.Container {
    background-color: green;
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display:table-cell;
}

.InnerContainer{
    background-color: blue;
    display: inline-block; /*just to wrap content*/
}
```

```html
<div class="Container">
    <div class="InnerContainer">
    <b><span class="large">Hi</span><span class="normal">How're you doing</span>
    <br/>
    <span style="font-family: Arial; font-size: medium">Answer Here</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

You don't need two containers, it can be done with just one. Do like that:

```css
.Container {
    background-color: green;
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display:table-cell;
}
```

```html
<div class="Container">
    <b><span class="large">Hi</span><span class="normal">How're you doing</span>
    <br/>
    <span style="font-family: Arial; font-size: medium">Answer Here</span>
</div>
```